# How can I use a push to deploy strategy to also pull data?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm using a push to deploy strategy like Heroku with one problem.  The user is also able to save favicons to the server and I want these on my local machine as well.

Is there a way to do this?  Is there a way I can do a git pull to pull the favicon files down.

The bare repo appears to have no way of knowing that files have been added to the working directory?

How is this normally handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files would need to be added to git (`git add ...`) at the server if I understand correctly. You could then commit those changes and pull them locally. However, a normal git workflow would be for "the user" to add, commit and push those changes to a central repository that you could then pull down from.

Comment: users on my site add data - favicons, images and what not...kind of like facebook ... I don't think it is normal but I want these in my git repo.  Otherwise I have to trust my service provider to back these items up.